# Injected HTTP client isn't defined during runtime

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, angular-httpclient

I'm attempting to use Angular's `HttpClient` in a service, but during runtime I'm encountering the following error:

```
ERROR TypeError: "this.http is undefined"
```

I'm importing HttpClientModule in my **app.module.ts**:

```
    import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
    ...

    @NgModule({
      imports: [
          HttpClientModule
          ...
      ],
      declarations: [AppComponent],
      bootstrap: [AppComponent]
    })
```

...and importing HttpClient in my **app.service.ts**:

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import DataSource from 'devextreme/data/data_source';
...
@Injectable()
export class Service {
    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

    getDataSource(): DataSource {
        return new DataSource({
            byKey: function (key) {
                return this.http.get("https://localhost/foobar" + encodeURIComponent(key))
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Does `this` refer to a different scope because it's in a new object? Do I need to pass `http` in somehow, or does dependency injection cover that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using arrow function to make sure that your this context refers to the current class instance:

Before:

```
byKey: function (key) {
```

After:

```
byKey: key => {
```